# Bash find -exec cp not all files are copyed

Tags: image, bash, copy, find

I am writing a bash script to find image files and to copy them to a dir.  My problem is when I use find it finds all files but when I add

```
-exec cp -n {} $2 \;
```

I know that I have set do not clobber but my test case takes this into account I also have a renaming mechanism in place later in the script that is tried and tested.

When I enter straight in terminal I get same problem

```
find Desktop -iname '*.JPG' -o -iname '*.jpeg' -o -iname '*.jf[il1]f' -o -iname '*.exif' -o -iname '*.tiff' -o -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.bmp' -o -iname '*.png'
```

I get (my test case 300 images in different dir with duplicates and same named file but for this problem simplified to these files on my desktop)

```
Desktop/IMG_0316.PNG
Desktop/IMG_0191.JPG
Desktop/IMG_0292.JPG
Desktop/IMG_0269.PNG
Desktop/IMG_0318.PNG
Desktop/IMG_0172.JPG
```

when I add cp command

```
find Desktop/ -iname '*.JPG' -o -iname '*.jpeg' -o -iname '*.jf[il1]f' -o -iname '*.exif' -o -iname '*.tiff' -o -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.bmp' -o -iname '*.png' -exec cp -n {} test \;
```

The only files I get in test are

```
Desktop/IMG_0316.PNG
Desktop/IMG_0269.PNG
Desktop/IMG_0318.PNG
```

I have tried removing -n from cp but made no diffrence
Thanks any help is appreciated

If I add echo I get

```
cp -n Desktop/IMG_0316.PNG test
cp -n Desktop/IMG_0269.PNG test
cp -n Desktop/IMG_0318.PNG test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parens

```
find Desktop/ \( -iname '*.JPG' -o -iname '*.jpeg' -o -iname '*.jf[il1]f' -o -iname '*.exif' -o -iname '*.tiff' -o -iname '*.gif' -o -iname '*.bmp' -o -iname '*.png' \) -exec cp -n {} test \;
```

Actually, `-exec` is an action while `-iname` is a predicate (a test in terms of [`man find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)). They aren't interchangeable at all. Default action is `-print`. So your expression means:

```
find Desktop -iname '*.JPG' -print \
    -o -iname '*.jpeg' -print -o ... -o -iname -iname '*.png' -exec cp...
```

By using parens your group tests and the provide a single action for the entire group.

Comment: Everything is a predicate. For example, you can do `find … -exec grep -qF foo {} \; -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/' {} \;` to only replace foo with bar in files that already contain "foo". (If you just do the sed part, you'll modify the mtime of many files unnecessarily.)

Comment: I would argue that actions _result codes_ may be used as tests, but I think that the topic starter doesn't expect to use find this way. Nevertheless, you're right and this is a helpful remark.